# MYSQL variable with CURSOR and FETCH

Tags: mysql

I wanted to use table names and run a statement with the table name as variable.  I used cursor/fetch but when I run a statement with the variable it is not using the value of the variable but just seems to use the variable_name itself. I have seen example with concat where another variable was defined but what if I just wanted to reference the table name in a COMMAND?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE v_table_name TEXT;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'rt';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done= TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

myloop: loop
  FETCH cur1 INTO v_table_name;

  IF done THEN
    LEAVE myloop;
  END IF;

  COMMAND table v_table_name;
END loop;

close cur1;
END $$
```

Answer (score 0):

If by **`COMMAND`** you mean you want to use the value of a variable as an *identifier* in another SQL statement... you may be able to make use of a prepared statement (in the context of a MySQL stored program).

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

As a trivial example of what that might look like:

```
  SET @sql = CONCAT('select * from `',v_table_name,'` limit 1');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
  SET @sql = NULL;
```

---

Note that this approach is *not* safe from SQL Injection vulnerabilities.

If that's not what you are looking for, I'm at a loss.  I don't understand what you are referring to as a **`COMMAND`**.

Comment: COMMAND as it something like: 

checksum table v_table_name;

or

select count(*) from v_table_name